# Efficient search in a permutation

Tags: algorithms, search

Let $S$ be an array of length $n$ containing a random permutation of numbers from $0$ to $n-1$. What is the most efficient (in expectation) algorithm for finding the location of a given number $k$ in $S$? In other words, finding index $i$, such that $S[i]=k$.

---

I watched a video about a related [puzzle](https://youtu.be/iSNsgj1OCLA) and it seems that in expectation we can do better than a linear search. The idea is to search $S[k]$ then $S[S[k]]$ then $S[S[S[k]]]$ and so on. I think this will find the required index faster than checking every element (on average), but I am not sure.

I wrote some Java [code](https://pastebin.com/2gU1dwMD) to simulate this algorithm and here are the results for $n=3$. I show every possible permutation and the number of steps required to find every possible $k$. Each element of the permutation is written in the form "index:value".

```
0:0 1:1 2:2
0 found in 1 steps
1 found in 1 steps
2 found in 1 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 1

0:0 1:2 2:1
0 found in 1 steps
1 found in 2 steps
2 found in 2 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 2

0:1 1:0 2:2
0 found in 2 steps
1 found in 2 steps
2 found in 1 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 2

0:1 1:2 2:0
0 found in 3 steps
1 found in 3 steps
2 found in 3 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 3

0:2 1:0 2:1
0 found in 3 steps
1 found in 3 steps
2 found in 3 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 3

0:2 1:1 2:0
0 found in 2 steps
1 found in 1 steps
2 found in 2 steps
maximum steps for this permutation 2

average of maximum steps for all permutations 2.1666666666666665
```

This algorithm has an average for all permutations of 2.17 steps. Meanwhile the linear algorithm of checking every element will always have an element that requires the maximum steps of 3, so its average over all permutations will be 3, which is worse.

As $n$ increases the number of steps required by the above algorithm seems to approach $2n/3$.

But can we do better?

Comment: No very elegant to silently modify the question. By the way, this order makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry I didn't change the question itself. I only added an idea for a solution. I am not sure if its optimal or what it's complexity is.

Comment: Also not elegant to disregard my answer.

Comment: Your answer may be optimal after all. I am just not sure yet.

Comment: Your description of the method is incomplete. In several cases, the search loops and does not find $k$.

Comment: For $n=3$, linear search takes at most $2$ comparisons, and on average $\dfrac 53$.

Comment: By the way, the average of the maximum times is *not* the average time.

Comment: My algorithm finds $k$ every time, it does not loop. If linear search begins with index 0 then 1 then 2, then for each permutation there will always be an element that requires $n$ steps.

Comment: Ok maybe I should call it average of worst case?

Comment: This is ambiguous because the worst case is on the set of permutations and the average is on $k$, and you could define the converse. In any case, this does not measure the *complexity* of the algorithm.

Comment: Actually, the worst case is for any $k$ for a given permutation. And the average is over all permutations.

Comment: So you see the ambiguity.

Comment: You still did not comment on the case of looping.

Comment: What do you mean by looping? Every element $k$ will be found in $n$ steps or less. This is true for any permutation.

Comment: $0\to1,1\to0$. Show us your code.

Comment: Right, so in that case you will find 0 after 2 steps. Let me upload my code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've added my code, so you can see exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 4):

Linear search.

Reading values from $S$ give you no information on where $k$ can be and you can't avoid exhaustive search. If the permutations are equiprobable, *whatever the order* in which you try the locations, the distribution of the number of trials is uniform. The expectation of the number of comparisons is $\dfrac{n-1}2$ (best case $1$, worst $n-1$).

Note that knowing the particular values (naturals $1$ to $n$) helps in no way.

---

**Update:**

The correct value of the expectation is

$$\frac{n^2+n-2}{2n},$$ my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a smaller example. Consider you have $10$ positions $[0, 1, 2, ..9]$ and the numbers are distributed as position $i$ has the number $(i + 1)mod10$. Now pick any $k$, it's easy to see that you'll have to traverse all the positions. So asymptotically, you have no benefit.

As far as expectation is concerned @Yves Daoust's answer gives you why it's unaffected. Also, implementing such a strategy in code isn't particularly helpful, it will only obfuscate the code, may make it harder for the compiler to optimize and may invalidate cache benefits if you are dealing with extremely large arrays.

Comment: In this particular case yes you would need to traverse all the positions. However, for a random permutation you would need to traverse fewer positions.

Comment: Even linear search would need to traverse fewer positions for "some random permutation" :)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: " you would need to traverse fewer positions": how do you justify this claim ? (By the way, you seem ignorant of the fact that in most cases the iteration $i=S[i]$ will loop and fail to find $k$.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've added an explanation in the question. I hope that helps?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: still quite insufficient. There is no analysis of the reason, and a mere "seems to".

Comment: The reason is explained in the linked video. The proposed algorithm divides a permutation into loops. The probability of a permutation having a loop of length $L$ is $1/L$. So long loops are unlikely. So the proposed algorithm is likely to terminate earlier in the worst case.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: how do you detect a loop ? What do you do after detecting a loop ?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: "likely to terminate earlier in the worst case": this is a free statement. Needs a rigorous probabilistic argument.

Comment: The loop terminates precisely when you have found $k$. At this point you exit the algorithm. Please watch the video, it explains this better than I can.